# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (u+2061) LateX

Tags: latex

The equations in my text are having the error Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (u + 2061). An example is the following equation.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \alpha = -1,38880 + 1,72027920\times10^{-2}t_{e} + 3,199\times10^{-2}  sen⁡(\omega t_{e} )- 2,65\times10^{-3}  cos⁡(\omega t_{e} ) + 4,05\times10^{-2} sen(2\omega t_{e} ) + 1,525\times10^{-2}  cos(\omega t_{e})
    \label{eq1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

How can I set it up to work?

Comment: Unrelated to the tex problem: are you sure that all the digits your show are significant figures?

Answer (score 1):

There are some invisible characters between `sen` and `⁡(\omega t_{e} )` and `cos` and `⁡(\omega t_{e} )`. Delete them and and code works again.

Unrelated to the problem:

- Instead of `cos` you should use `\cos`.
- If `sen` is used as the Italian/Spanish/whatever version of `\sin`, than this should also be typeset upright. Packages like `babel` provide the macro `\sen` to do this.
- If you write numbers with `1,38880` the spacing around the decimal separator will be wrong. To fix this use `1{,}38880` or the `icomma` package or use dedicated macros from the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
  \alpha = -1,38880 + 1,72027920\times10^{-2}t_{e} + 3,199\times10^{-2}  \sen(\omega t_{e} )- 2,65\times10^{-3}  \cos(\omega t_{e} ) + 4,05\times10^{-2} \sen(2\omega t_{e} ) + 1,525\times10^{-2}  \cos(\omega t_{e})
  \label{eq1}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```